# mongo-go-driver: nested OR/AND query filter

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I try to create a MongoDB query filter with the nested operators (OR/AND/...). But lib requires to create a `bson.D` and pass `bson.E` elements into it. If I need to have `OR/AND` inside `AND/OR` - I need to put `bson.M + bson.D` inside `bson.D` like this:

```
filter := bson.M{"$and": bson.D{{"p", 10}, bson.M{"$or": bson.D{{"s", 30}, {"a", 1}}}}}
```

.. and of course it doesn't work: `cannot use primitive.M literal (type primitive.M) as type primitive.E in slice literal`. Probably the same problem will happen if later I try to use a `... in []` logics inside a `bson.D`

How do I create such nested queries in Go and official MongoDB driver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What matters is that `$or` requires an array, which is [`bson.A`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#A). Also `$and` is the default, you don't have to indicate that.

Your filter can be defined like this:

```
filter := bson.D{
    {"p", 10},
    {"$or", bson.A{
        bson.D{{"s", 30}},
        bson.D{{"a", 10}},
    }},
}
```

You may also use this:

```
filter = bson.D{
    {"p", 10},
    {"$or", bson.A{
        bson.M{"s": 30},
        bson.M{"a": 10},
    }},
}
```

Or this:

```
filter := bson.M{
    "p": 10,
    "$or": bson.A{
        bson.M{"s": 30},
        bson.M{"a": 10},
    },
}
```