# Mongo-go-driver nested query golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I used to have two filters to get data from my mongoDB, however I do not think that it is efficient considering it has to do two queries to the DB.

```
    filter = bson.M{
        "$and": []bson.M{
            {"partnerA.id": id},
            {"unlocked": false},
            {"deletedAt": nil},
        },
    }
```

```
    filter = bson.M{
        "$and": []bson.M{
            {"partnerB.id": id},
            {"unlocked": false},
            {"deletedAt": nil},
        },
    }
```

I tried to combine them using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60969262/mongo-go-driver-nested-or-and-query-filter) solution I found and came out with this filter:

```
    filter := bson.M{
        "$and": []bson.M{
            {"partnerA.id": id},
            {"unlocked": false},
            {"deletedAt": nil},
        },
        "$or": bson.A{
            bson.M{"$and": []bson.M{
                {"partnerB.id": id},
                {"unlocked": false},
                {"deletedAt": nil},
            }},
        },
    }
```

However it does not work and I can't find the solution for it. Does anyone see the problem for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are trying to combine those two queries with `OR` operator. Another thing, I saw two similar clauses between the two, it's `"unlocked": false` and `"deletedAt": nil`.

You can have shorter query like below:

```golang
filter := bson.M{
    "$or": []bson.M{
        {"partnerA.id": id},
        {"partnerB.id": id},
    },
    "unlocked": false,
    "deletedAt": nil,
}
```

---

##### Update #1

> How about a new query where I only return the values if ((partnerA.id = id and partnerA.unlocked = true) or (partnerB.id = id and partnerB.unlocked = true))
> Blockquote

```golang
filter := bson.M{
    "$or": []bson.M{
        {
            "partnerA.id": id,
            "partnerA.unlocked": true,
        },
        {
            "partnerB.id": id,
            "partnerB.unlocked": true,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. It's working as it was supposed to now!

Comment: I have another question. How about a new query where I only return the values if ((partnerA.id = id and partnerA.unlocked = true) or (partnerB.id = id and partnerB.unlocked = true))

Comment: @Marius please check my updated answer